# How do I verify the URL that ActiveResource intends to use on a call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, activerecord, activeresource

I'm trying to request data from another Rails app, but I keep getting a "URL not found" error.
Is it possible to use the debugger to figure out the intended URL and parameters for an intended ActiveResource call?

For example, I'd like to make a GET request with the following parameters:

```
https://some_server.com/employees/search.xml?last_name=smith
```

And I have the following ActiveResource model

```
class Employee < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://some_server.com"
end
```

And the some_server.com app has a search action that maps this way:

```
map.connect "/employees/search.:format", :controller => 'employees', :action => 'search'
```

But when I try this:

```
Employee.new(:last_name => 'smith).get(:search)
```

I get a 404 "Service not found" error. To me, that sounds like the URL that ACtiveResource is requesting is incorrect, 'cause when I make the above request via a browser, I get the xml. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Cheerio,
Berns

Comment: what is your log in server ? The request really call. I suppose it's not what you suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I'm supposed to be calling this:

```
Employee.get(:search, :last_name => 'smith')
```

NOT what I showed above.

Comment: That solves your particular issue, but did you find an answer to the question of debugging the intended URL?

Answer (score 4):

Using the collection_path method on ActiveResource should do the trick, check out the answer here:

[How do you log the URL ActiveResource uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663972/how-do-you-log-the-url-activeresource-uses/7773091#7773091)