# How do you log the URL ActiveResource uses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, activeresource

Rails ActiveResource is awesome ... except for one thing: as far as I can tell, there is no way to see what URL it is using behind the scenes.  For instance, let's say I have an ActiveResource called Issue, for a webservice at myIssues.com/issues.xml.  If I do:

```
Issue.find(:all, :params => {:page => 2})
```

I would expect that ActiveResource would make a call to:

```
myIssues.com/issues.xml?page=2
```

... but I don't actually know that.  For all I know, ActiveResource could have decided it doesn't like the word "page", so it's actually using:

```
myIssues.com/issues.xml?mod_page=2
```

This makes debugging difficult.  Right now I've got a situation where, if I go to the URL I *think* ActiveResource is using, it works just fine.  However, when I actually use ActiveResource, it doesn't work.  Seeing the URL it's GETing would be immensely helpful in this, so ...

Does anyone know a way to log (or otherwise output; if there's some resource.url method that would work great too) the URL(s) that ActiveResource uses to do its thing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you add the following line to your `environment.rb` file, it will at least log the requests so you know that URLs `ActiveResource` is hitting:

```
ActiveResource::Base.logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
```

I'm still searching for a better solution that shows me the response and the data posted to update calls, but at least this is a step in the right direction.  I'm really not sure why `ActiveResource` has a separate logger to start with, but that's another matter.

Comment: If you're not using ActiveRecord, just use a separate logger:

`active_resource_logger = Logger.new('log/active_resource.log', 'daily');
active_resource_logger.level = Rails.env.dev? ? Logger::DEBUG : Logger::INFO;

ActiveResource::Base.logger = active_resource_logger`

Comment: I know this is super old, but the http_logger gem (https://github.com/railsware/http_logger) works great for this. You can see the HTTP request that gets sent to the ActiveResource site and any errors that it might spit back out at you when you set `HttpLogger.log_request_body = true`

Comment: You can also do `ActiveResource::Base.logger = Rails.logger` if you aren't using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this same exact issue, and came across this post as I was looking for answers.  What I did find, that proved useful, is the collection_path method on ActiveResource::Base.  So for example, let's say you have the following resource:

```
class UserPost < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://someApp.com/user/:user_id"
    self.element_name = "post"
```

If you go to the rails console, here are some examples of the output:

```
>> UserPost.collection_path
"/user//post"
>> UserPost.collection_path(:user_id => 5)
"/user/5/post
```

This should provide you with exactly what you need to determine how ActiveResource is translating your request into a URL.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**To get detail login** for ActiveResource have to patch the request method inside the gem([method](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/0ae3010f505b5e6063b7acbcd22cc221995e7873/lib/active_resource/connection.rb#L128).

place bellow files inside `config/initializers` you will get **http method, path, request body, request hedaers**

**response body and header** is already there if you need. [doc](https://github.com/rails/activeresource#logging)

*config/initializers/activeresource_patch.rb*

```
module ActiveResource
  class Connection
    private
      def request(method, path, *arguments)
        result = ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("request.active_resource") do |payload|
          payload[:method]      = method
          payload[:request_uri] = "#{site.scheme}://#{site.host}:#{site.port}#{path}"
          payload[:request_path] = path
          payload[:request_body] = arguments[0]
          payload[:request_headers] = arguments[1]
          payload[:result]      = http.send(method, path, *arguments)
        end
        handle_response(result)
      rescue Timeout::Error => e
        raise TimeoutError.new(e.message)
      rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
        raise SSLError.new(e.message)
      end
  end
end
```

*config/initializers/activeresource_logger.rb*

```
Rails.application.configure do

  def activeresource_logger
  @activeresource_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/activeresource_logger.log")
  end

  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe('request.active_resource')  do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
   if Rails.env.development?
    activeresource_logger.info("====================== #{start} : #{payload[:method].upcase} ======================")
    activeresource_logger.info("PATH: #{payload[:request_path]}")
    activeresource_logger.info("BODY: #{payload[:request_body]}")
    activeresource_logger.info("HEADERS: #{payload[:request_headers]}")
    # activeresource_logger.info("STATUS_CODE: #{payload[:result].code}")
    # activeresource_logger.info("RESPONSE_BODY: #{payload[:result].body}")
   end
  end

end
```